# Getting directory from PageFiles folder of EPiServer

Tags: c#, episerver, episerver-6

I'm having some thoughts about how the EPiServer PageFiles system work. When I get a global file it's simple to get the correct directory, I just write:

```
var dir = VirtualPathHandler.Instance.GetDirectory("~/Global/myfolder/", true)
```

But when I want to get files from the PageFiles folder it gets tricky for me. The path in the EPi backoffice upload says it is `PageFiles/myfolder`, but this doesn't return any folders

```
var dir = VirtualPathHandler.Instance.GetDirectory("~/PageFiles/myfolder/", true)
```

Now I see that files are saved different for each page, one page has the path `/PageFiles/361/myfolder/` and another page has the path `/PageFiles/65/myfolder/`. All I want to do is be able to write

```
var dir = VirtualPathHandler.Instance.GetDirectory("~/PageFiles/myfolder/", true)
```

but to get any folder I have to write (for instance)

```
var dir = VirtualPathHandler.Instance.GetDirectory("~/PageFiles/65/myfolder/", true)
```

What is the correct way to get a PageFiles folder so I can access all files in it?

BTW, this is EPiServer 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the GetPageDirectory method on your PageData object

http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/html/M_EPiServer_Core_PageData_GetPageDirectory.htm

Comment: Thanks, I havn't had time to test yet but from reading about uploading files to a page's file folder this is correct!